# I want to understand why React state is updating my array in this way

Tags: reactjs

I need to track the set of items a user selects. I initialized the component's state to contain an array to hold the set of data-ids the user clicks.

Each item contains an "onClick" listener and a data-id attribute with a value:

```
<div onClick={this.selectItem} data-id={this.props.id}>Select this item</div>
```

My class and method:

```
class Item extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.selectItem = this.selectItem.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      itemsSelected: []
    };
  }

  selectItem(e) {
    const id = e.target.dataset.id;

    // copy state to new array with the new value
    let itemsSelected = [...this.state.itemsSelected, id];

    // Set state and display it, after update occurred
    this.setState({ itemsSelected }, function() {
      console.log('itemsSelected: ', this.state.itemsSelected);
    }); 
  }
```

I would expect the console log to display a growing set of ids as items are clicked, however it displays only the last item clicked (array length is always 1). YET, if the same item is clicked, the array grows.

So, clicking item 1, then 2, then 3 results in the state being set with an array of one value of 3. And clicking item 1 three times results in an array of 3 values, each being the value of 1.

I want the array to contain the ids of any/all items the user clicks.

Project dependencies:

"dependencies": {
  "history": "4.2.0",
  "re-base": "2.2.0",
  "react": "15.3.2",
  "react-addons-css-transition-group": "15.3.2",
  "react-dom": "15.3.2",
  "react-router": "4.0.0-alpha.4"
},

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like each of your `Items` handles its own clicks and stores its own `itemsSelected` array inside its own `state`. What you have to do is to introduce some sort of `ItemsContainer` which will subscribe to `Item's` clicks and will have this way one `itemsSelected` which in turn will collect all selections.

**UPDATE:**

Ok, here is detailed explanation. Each React `Component` have its own state. When you call `this.setState` inside component only its state will be updated:

```
              +---------------------+
              |       Item          |
    updates   |                     |
 +----------> |state: { ... }       |
 |            |                     |   calls
 +----------+ |this.setState({ ... }| <----------+
              |                     |            |
              |this.selectItem  +----------------+
              |                     |
              +---------------------+
```

When you renders several `Item` `Components` (and looks like you do) each of them will have its own state. Let's say you renders two `Items` with ids 1 and 2. Initially they both will have empty `itemsSelected` arrays as their state:

```
 +------------------------+    +------------------------+
 |       Item (id = 1)    |    |       Item (id = 2)    |
 |                        |    |                        |
 | state: {               |    | state: {               |
 |   itemsSelected: []    |    |   itemsSelected: []    |
 | }                      |    | }                      |
 +------------------------+    +------------------------+
```

Each of them will have it's own `selectItem` handler updating its own state. After you'll click first one 2 times and click second once their states will be:

```
 +------------------------+    +------------------------+
 |       Item (id = 1)    |    |       Item (id = 2)    |
 |                        |    |                        |
 | state: {               |    | state: {               |
 |   itemsSelected: [1, 1]|    |   itemsSelected: [2]   |
 | }                      |    | }                      |
 +------------------------+    +------------------------+
```

And that is exactly what you see in your console. What you have to do is to introduce another `ItemContainer` which will render all the items and listen to their selections. To subscribe to `Item's` selection it must pass callback function inside `Items`' props. `Items` in turn will invoke that callback inside their `selectItem` handlers.

```
+---------------------+                      +---------------------+
|       Item          |                      |    ItemContainer    |
|                     |       pass onSelect  |                     |
|                     | <--------------------+this.render          |
|   this.selectItem   |                      |                     |  calls
|         +           |                      |this.setState({ ... }| <-------+
|         |           | this.props.onSelect  |                     |         |
|         +--------------------------------> |this.onSelect +----------------+
+---------------------+                      +---------------------+
```

Comment: hmm... so an element can have its own state? So how then do I access the component's state? I thought I was doing that. I need to update the itemsSelected property of the component's state. Sorry I'm not following your response. I'm very new to React.

Comment: @MarkSalvatore elaborated a bit on my explanation.

Comment: Oh I see. Maybe I just need to put selectItem() in the parent component where it can manage the Item child component. I probably just need to pass the method down to <Item> and things will behave as hoped. Does that sound right?

Comment: @MarkSalvatore yeah, exactly what I tried to explain.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `setState` is asynchronous. You can't rely on the state from the setState :

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: Right, and that's why I included the callback function in setState(). I believe that callback should ensure seeing state only AFTER it updates.

Comment: I think it's because React tries to group up similar setState to minimize calls. In your example, you are doing nothing with setState ? a `this.setState({ itemsSelected }, function() {
      return { itemsSelected };
    }); ` could do the thing

Comment: But I do call setState(). As I understand it, setState() can be passed a callback function when the state gets set, whereby I chose to console.log the updated state.